# How can I delete all characters in each line of a text file that begins with a particular string?

Tags: text-processing

I need to delete all characters beginning with 'of' in each line as follows:

> Acer_BB1_Locus_1_Transcript_2of285068_Confidence_0.000_Length_1696

> Acer_BB1_Locus_1_Transcript_2

Comment: So you just need to delete everything after the appearance of `of`?  because the way you have it worded does not say that.

Comment: I have downvoted since the question is really trivial. There are a tons of questions and ansers here, and in other stack* site. Apart from that what have you tried? Whith which tool? Wtih which language? with which shell? What we need to do with lines that does not hold an `of` at all?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the input is valid text in the user's locale, you can do:

```
sed 's/of.*//' < input
```

That substitutes `of` and any amount (`*`) of *characters* (`.`) following it (so would stop at the first byte that does not form part of a valid character in the locale in most `sed` implementations¹) with the empty string.

If you can't guarantee the  encoding of the input matches the user's locale, and that it is not one of those character encodings where some characters other than `o` have their encoding ending in that of `o` (such as BIG5², BIG5-HKSCS, GBK, GB18030), you could do:

```
LC_ALL=C sed 's/of.*//' < input
```

As an example of the issue with non-text input, or input encoded in a different charmap from that of the locale and with the GNU implementation of `sed`:

```
$ locale charmap
UTF-8
$ printf 'Point of St\351phane\n' | sed 's/of.*//'
Point �phane
$ printf 'Point of St\351phane\n' | LC_ALL=C sed 's/of.*//'
Point
```

(here with a `Stéphane` encoded in latin-1 or latin-0 being processed by a `sed` running in a locale with a UTF-8 charmap where 0xe9 (0351) alone cannot form part of a valid character).

As an example of the issue with character encodings such as BIG5-HKSCS:

```
$ echo trèfle of concern | iconv -t BIG5-HKSCS | LC_ALL=C sed 's/of.*//'
tr�
$ echo trèfle of convern | iconv -t BIG5-HKSCS | LC_ALL=zh_HK.big5hkscs sed 's/of.*//' | iconv -f BIG5-HKSCS
trèfle
```

As the U+00E8 `è` character there is encoded as 0x88 0x6f, 0x6f also being the encoding of `o`. You need `sed` to run in a locale that uses that charmap for those characters to be decoded properly.

---

<sup>¹ some `sed` implementations could also just fail with an error that the input cannot be decoded in those cases</sup>

<sup>² Acer, which you mention, being one of those big 5s who invented that charset.</sup>